# Formatting computer (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-10, formatting

I made my pen drive bootable, and tried formatting pc with windows 10, I formatted my **System drive** and proceed further, but because of some reason it come up with error message, I then tried formatting with win 7, it came up with following screen (red light is flash of camera), please help.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the BIOS and make sure disk is detected and properly ordered for booting

Comment: how to do these?

Comment: If it is Intel Motherboard press F10 and select your pen drive as boot device and install the OS.